# Virtual box based development for windows

Tags: windows, fedora, virtualbox

I would like to convert my entire development setup to a virtual box based environment.

Is there a minimal-OS which we can install on our laptop and run virtual box based windows XP or Vista or 7 or even linux on which we can do the development?

My problem is if I have a windows xp or 7 installed, then the amount of memory I can allocate to this virtual box runtime gets limited to around 50% of my available physical memory.

So ultimately I would like the resultant guest image to have the maximum RAM and the host can be a no-brainer OS.

I see some answers in stackoverflow which are quite old. But I believe there should be some updated latest versions in virtualbox which are probably worth knowing.

Comment: I believe Linux is much better choice for host OS than Windows. Perhaps, a server edition of some Linux OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this depends on what sort of development you're talking about.  If you're writing scripts or small applications then performance in a VM may be adequate.  If you're building moderate or large C/C++ applications then the performance is likely to be horrendous.  Any development activity that relies on a large amount of I/O such as C/C++ compilation will suffer in a VM.  I believe that VMs can get quite decent CPU performance, so if your development activity is more CPU than disk bound then this might be workable.  If you're only allocating 50% of your RAM to the VM then performance is going to be constrained even further.

Comment: Hmm! My objective is to move my C# & C++ Visual Studio 2008/2010 development environment to VirtualBox. So your answer means, I cannot do this. Is this correct?

Comment: I didn't say that you can't do this, just that if these are large projects then it _may_ be intolerably slow to run them in a virtual machine.  If you are running on a laptop then I wouldn't expect you'd get good performance unless it's really fast with lots of RAM.  YMMV.

Comment: yeah, got it. But there is no reason why someone would choose to do development work in a slow environment :). So my question was to make a decision yes or no. It is obviously a no. So thanks for your answer.

Comment: I would try it before you rule it out completely, if you're writing really small apps then performance may be acceptable.  But it's worth having low expectations and then anything better is a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 2):

I do cross platform development. Whilst Visual Studio is more hungry than the Linux equivalents it's still good in a VM. Windows I believe splits physical ram into two equal chunks on 32 bit systems. Half for the kernel and half for the user process. VirtualBox suffers from this split. VMware player doesn't seem to have the same issue. Running on Linux VirtualBox seems much happier and Linux can be VERY light weight. Minimal install of Debian or CentOS would be my choice.

When comparing VM dev environments and real ones, I found that the VM one was slower by say 10-15% percent compared to compiling on the host (VMs shut down), However the host had more memory and more CPUs at its disposal. The VM can be easily deployed where ever you want was well - really cool.

What you want to do makes sense. Just make sure you have 2-4 CPUs and at least 1.5-2GB of memory in your VM for MSVS2008 if you are dealing with a fairly large project (perhaps refrain from using 2010 unless it specifically gives you a feature that you want as it is more resource hungry).

The only compilation thing that sucks big time is when building over a network. SMB is dreadful, NFS and Nix you'd hardly notice the difference to using a local disk most of the time.

Hope this helps. Oh and yes I have been using a Windows XP dev VM on a project that is GBs in size (source code wise).

Good luck. T.

Answer (score 1):

Slackware? If you really want to cut down on things. Otherwise, a LiveCD variant, copied to the HD, and modified to include VirtualBox should work.

Comment: Is slackware a reliable OS? Does it have GUI? I have used it 10 years back and haven't looked at it after that.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still an update for 2016.

I spent the whole day trying. I have an experimental task to do at work. I am running it on 3 Linux VMs on Virtualbox (Win 2008 server host) before moving it to real servers.

I tried lightweight Linux variants like Lubuntu and Bodhi. Lubuntu had problems with graphics. It would go blank if I change the screen size. Bodhi is good but a bit unintuitive.

I found Linux Mint with XFCE to be the best compromise between lightweight, functionality and UI experience. It resizes automatically when VirtualBox window is maximised. No problems installing guest additions too.

Earlier last year, I had run IntelliJ Idea on LinuxMint 17.3 as guest VM running on Virtualbox on a Ubuntu 14.04.x LTS host. It was fairly fast, I had a Core i7 with 16 GB of RAM though.